# Questionnaire GUI (my first GUI) skips my questions?

Tags: java, swing

I am attempting to create a simple GUI that asks the user a series of questions, and then stores their responses for assignment later.  I have determined my error is in my method that basically executes the simply 7 question problem.  I have added the 7 questions into an ArrayList, created an empty ArrayList for my answers, but when I run the method, the only thing it displays is the text for the very last question.

Obviously a Java noob, but 100% a GUI/swing/AWT noob, and really feel like I have no idea what I'm doing, so any time or effort anyone is willing to put forth in an attempt to educate me would be GREATLY appreciated and I thank you in advance!!

```
public class ORMRiskCalculator extends JFrame{

private JButton yesButton, noButton, exitButton, enterButton;
private JLabel message;
private JTextField textField;
private JFrame frmOrmRiskCalculator;
private final ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
//int's needed to create a personnel Risk


private ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<Integer> responses = new ArrayList<Integer>();

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ORMRiskCalculator window = new ORMRiskCalculator();
                window.frmOrmRiskCalculator.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public ORMRiskCalculator() {
    setupQuestions();
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frmOrmRiskCalculator = new JFrame();
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0, 102, 153));
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.setTitle("ORM Risk Calculator");
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.setBounds(100, 100, 650, 500);
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    message = new JLabel("Create a new ORM Report?");
    message.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    message.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    message.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
    message.setBounds(10, 10, 614, 109);
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.getContentPane().add(message);


    yesButton = new JButton("YES");
    yesButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    yesButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    yesButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    yesButton.setBounds(80, 240, 200, 50);      
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.getContentPane().add(yesButton);
    yesButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            calcPersonnelRisk();
        }
    });

    noButton = new JButton("NO");
    noButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
    noButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    noButton.setBounds(80, 330, 200, 50);
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.getContentPane().add(noButton);
    noButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(350, 275, 100, 50);
    textField.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    enterButton = new JButton("Enter");
    enterButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14)); 
    enterButton.setBounds(450, 275, 100, 50);
    buttonGroup.add(enterButton);
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.getContentPane().add(enterButton);

    exitButton = new JButton("EXIT");
    exitButton.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    exitButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 18));
    exitButton.setBounds(80, 425, 470, 25);
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.getContentPane().add(exitButton);
    exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        shutDown();
        }
    });
}

private void setupQuestions(){
    questions.add("How many mission personnel had less than normal rest?");
    questions.add("How many mission personnel have an illness that may impact the mission?");
    questions.add("How many mission personnel are taking medications that may affect duty?");
    questions.add("How many mission personnel are scheduled to work longer than ten hours?");
    questions.add("How many mission personnel worked greater than ten hours on the previous shift?");
    questions.add("How many mission personnel are still in a training status(less than fulll-time, T-RCOs)??");
    questions.add("How many mission personnel are on duty during flight operations?");
}
private void calcPersonnelRisk() {
    yesButton.setVisible(false);
    noButton.setVisible(false);
    message.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    for (int i=0; i<questions.size(); i++){
    message.setText(questions.get(i));
    enterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                int r= Integer.parseInt(textField.getText().trim());
                responses.add(r);            
            }});
    }
}

private void shutDown(){
    message.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 26));
    message.setText("Good bye!");//why doesn't this work? Sleeps, and closes, 
    //doesn't show my text message.

    try {
         Thread.sleep(1000);//also tried a wait(), notify(), but it seemed like the notify never allowed it to get to the exit command
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    System.exit(0);
}//end shutDown method
}//endORMRiskCalculator
```

Comment: if `message` is a JTextField/JLabel, so it will display the last index of your ArrayList, that means (index 6), you update its value in every iteration in your loop

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cycle through the questions, you can't load them all at once.

Something like this should load the next question when you click the enter button.

```
private int questionIndex; // store which question youre on 

private void calcPersonnelRisk() {
    yesButton.setVisible(false);
    noButton.setVisible(false);
    message.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    // load the first question 
    message.setText(questions.get(questionIndex++));

    enterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int r= Integer.parseInt(textField.getText().trim());
            responses.add(r);

            // load the next question 
            if (questionIndex < questions.size()) {
                message.setText(questions.get(questionIndex++));
            } else {
                message.setText("Done");
            }
        }});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That allowed me to at least start at one and step through...I still don't understand why my for loop screwed it up...but at this point, any progress is monumental!  just need to add a while (maybe?) to handle the OB, and add a setText("") somewhere to add the positive reinforcement that "something" happened when I clicked enter (besides cycling questions).  Additionally I want to add a KeyListener so the user can click enter, or also use the enter key.

Comment: That's a long list of things you're welcome to create additional posts for, but the for loop was looping over all question strings, and you only were seeing the very last one, and not waiting for any input for them

Comment: And no white loops. You just need an if statement when  the question index is greater than the question list size, set the text to "done", or empty.

Comment: Lol, yah...I just spent the last 10 minutes figuring out the hard way that while loops just pretty much either immediately give me an outOfBounds ex, or give me the same problem I had before.  Once I get that figure out, need to "close" the method calcPersonnelRisk, so then I can write my method that will just use the int's gathered to determine a "PersonnelRisk" and make a recommendation (via the message screen) before closing.

Comment: So, I've tried a few variations on the if condition to get it to stop adding 1 to the counter and "do something else..." but it still throws out of bounds as soon as the last question is answered... I'll add the fix under my code above.

Comment: Please don't edit my answers. Your new error is a different problem, which is better suited for a new post. My answer here seems to address the question you initially asked about

Comment: Understood..I realized I accidentally edited your response, so when I tried to go change it back to how it was and just edit MY initialy post, it told me I needed to change at least 6 characters and wouldn't allow me to "undo" the edit of your answer.  My apologies, I will create a new post.  I thank you for your time and again apologize.

Comment: No worries. I've edited my answer for how I would have handled it